# Scala view bound in collection type

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion

I have a collection of elements that are implicitly convertible to, say, String. How to make it look like an actual collection of Strings?

```
def foo[A <% String](it: Iterator[A]) = {
  val its: Iterator[String] = ???
}
```

(I am aware that view bounds are deprecated but let us assume that signature of `foo` is fixed, overriding a legacy method.)

One solution I could come up with is defining a trivial converter class between `Iterator[A]` and `Iterator[String]`, but that could be cumbersome for other collection classes with many abstract methods. Is there a standard way of handling this situation, without significant extra code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`A <% String` is just sugar for an implicit `A => String`

```
def foo[A](it: Iterator[A])(conv: A => String) = {
  val its: Iterator[String] = it map conv
}
```

(If you really want to use the `<%` syntax you can obtain the function within the block using `implicitly[A => String]`)